# Monitoring the OpenSSH sFTP process?

Tags: ssh, monitoring, sftp

Is there a way to monitor the current status of my sFTP process from my Debian server?

I'm looking from something similar to `top` or `netstat` that will give me the status/progress of activities (uploads, downloads) to my OpenSSH-based sFTP server.

Other bits that might be of use: I'll be looking at the results using a SSH session on the server.  There is only one sFTP enabled user.

Comment: You can use ntop (on Debian) to look at network throughput.  But it won't show you individual sFTP sessions the way you mention.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `iptraf` in order to give you real time information.

It will give you following information per port number (in your case, the default port would be 22): # of packets, # of bytes, #of packets From/To, #of bytes From/to.

It won't show you individual sFTP sessions though.